# Angular 2 material : sidenav toggle from component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular-material2

I'm using Angular 2 Material sidenav in my project this way:

```
<md-sidenav-layout>
  <md-sidenav #start mode="side" [opened]="true">
      <md-nav-list>
      </md-nav-list>
  </md-sidenav>

  <button md-button (click)="start.toggle()">Close</button>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</md-sidenav-layout>
```

How to call `start.toggle()` from my component instead of element with click event?

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 18):

You want to declare a `ViewChild` in your controller that references the `MdSidenav` inside your component, like this:

```
// Sidemenu
@ViewChild('start') sidenav: MdSidenav;
```

where `start` is the name of the component you want to reference, in this case the sidenav.

Next you can call methods on that sidenav, like `this.sidenav.toggle()` inside your controller's functions.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child

Answer (score 11):

Pass the object to your function.

```html
<md-sidenav-layout>
  <md-sidenav #start mode="side" [opened]="true">
      <md-nav-list>
      </md-nav-list>
  </md-sidenav>

  <button md-button (click)="randomName(start)">Close</button>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</md-sidenav-layout>
```

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {
    }

    randomName(start: any) {
        start.toggle();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way for was to pass the drawer to the component that triggers the toggle.

**Html:**

```
<mat-drawer #drawer mode="side">
    ....
</mat-drawer>

<another-component [drawerRef]="drawer"><another-component/>
```

**another-component TS:**

```
export class AnotherComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() drawerRef: MatDrawer;
   ...
}
```

**another-component HTML:**

```
<button (click)="this.drawerRef.toggle()">
```

Where another-component is the component that controls the toggle action.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <md-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav" opened="false">
    <div class="example-sidenav-content">
      <button type="button" md-button (click)="toogleNav(sidenav)">
        toogle
      </button>
    </div>
 </md-sidenav>
```

And in your ts:

```
export class AppComponent {

  toogleNav(nav: any) {
    if (nav.opened) {
      nav.close()
    } else {
      nav.open();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The sidenav has a toggle() method